# Design the info member and search function in the queue class in c++

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I have been trying to solve this problem the whole day and not able to . So i have a queue class and and graph class where i have to complete the graph class by implementing the missing functions in the queue . So i am attaching below the code :

> Queue Class

```
class Queue {
int front, rear, capacity;
int* queue;
Queue(int c)
{
    front = rear = 0;
    capacity = c;
    queue = new int;
}

~Queue() { delete[] queue; }

void enqueue(int data)
{

    if (capacity == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        queue[rear] = data;
        rear++;
    }
    return;
}

void queueDequeue()
{

    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is  empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < rear - 1; i++) {
            queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
        }
        rear--;
    }
    return;
}

void queueDisplay()
{
    int i;
    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = front; i < rear; i++) {
        printf(" %d <-- ", queue[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void queueFront()
{
    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nFront Element is: %d", queue[front]);
    return;
}
};
```

> Graph Class

class graph{

private:
int node_count;

```
 graph(int n)
{
    if(n<1)
    {
        node_count=0; node_label=NULL; edges=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node_label= (char *)malloc(20*n);
        if(node_label==NULL)
        {
            node_count=0;
            edges=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            edges=(Queue *)malloc(n*sizeof(Queue));
            if(edges==NULL)
            {
                node_count=0;
                free(node_label);
                node_label=NULL;
            }
            else

                node_count=n;

        }

    }

}    // End of parameterized Constructor



int set_edge(int from, int to, float wt=1)
{
    queue_info_type data;
    Queue_NODE temp;
    int status;
    if((from<0) || (from>=n))
        return 0;
    if((to<0) || (to>=n))
        return 0;
    if(from==to) //Simple graph
        return 0;
    if(wt<=0) //positive weighted graph
        return 0;

    temp=edges[from].search(to); //searches for the "to" in the corresponding
    //field  of the info of queue node, if found
    //returns the address of the node,
    //if not found returns NULL
    if(temp!=NULL)
        return 0;  //Edge from-to already exist
    data.dest=to;
    data.wt=wt;
    status=edges[from].queueEnqueue(data);

    if(status==1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


float get_weight(int from, int to)
{
    if((from<0) || (from>=n))
        return 0;
    if((to<0) || (to>=n))
        return 0;
    if(from==to) //Simple graph
        return 0;
    temp=edges[from].front;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp.info.dest==to)
            return (temp.info.wt);
        temp=temp->ptr;
    }
    return 0;
}


int set_label(int which, char *what)
{
    char *cur;
    if(which<0) && ( which>=node_count)
    return 0; // invalid node
    if(strlen(what)>19)
        what[19]='\0'; //Labels are maximum 19 symbol long
    cur=node_label+(20*which);
    strcpy(cur,what);
    return 1;
}
int show_label(int which)
{
    char *cur;
    if(which<0) && ( which>=node_count)
    {       print("invalid");
        return 0; // invalid node
    }
    cur=node_label+(20*which);
    printf("%s",cur);
    return 1;
}
};
```

So basically i have to do some changes and add the info member and search function in the queue class such that the graph class works properly . But i am unable to. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `new int` allocates memory for exactly 1 `int`. Did you mean `new int[capacity]`?

Comment: And do not use `malloc` in C++, it does not call constructors.

Comment: My university professor said that i have to for this specific task

Comment: Did he tell you how to use placement `new` then? Because `malloc` can only be used in C++ if followed by placement `new`. Regular `new Queue[n]` would work without all that work.

Comment: Please show me according to your opinion what the program should be . I am a complete beginner and facing much difficulty

Comment: @BytesBots: Your university teacher is trying to teach you a language that became obsolete in the previous century. In every form of standard C++, you would use `std::vector<int>`. This site tries to encourage good answers, which is unfortunately not what your professor demands.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too specific - bad professor.